# Get only those rows whose order status of all the line items corresponding to same order number is same

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following is my table structure with data

```
id  orderNO lineItemNO  orderStatus
1   100     1           Processing
2   100     2           Processing
3   100     3           Pending
4   101     1           Pending
5   101     2           Pending
```

i have orderNo and line item no column which represents the no of products in the order. Now i want only that orders and lineItemNo whose orderStatus is same.

for example

Order No with 100 has 3 line items (1,2,3) but line item no (1 and 2) has orderStatus as Processing ans line item no (3) has orderStatus has Pending so i dont want this order.

Now order No with 101 has 2 line items (1,2) and all line items from the same order has the same order status so i need order 101.

So looking for the SQL query for the same.

I need output as

```
id  orderNO lineItemNO  orderStatus
4   101     1           Pending
5   101     2           Pending
```

Please Help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some creative thinking about sets should demonstrate that we can determine this by finding the `MIN()` and `MAX()` values within each group and comparing them - if they're equal then there cannot be any other value within the same group:

```
declare @t table (id int,orderNO int,lineItemNO int,orderStatus varchar(317))
insert into @t(id,orderNO,lineItemNO,orderStatus) values
(1,100,1,'Processing'),
(2,100,2,'Processing'),
(3,100,3,'Pending'),
(4,101,1,'Pending'),
(5,101,2,'Pending')

;With MinMax as (
    select *,
        MIN(orderStatus) OVER (PARTITION BY orderNo) as minStat,
        MAX(orderStatus) OVER (PARTITION BY orderNo) as maxStat
    from
        @t
)
select * from MinMax where minStat = maxStat
```

Produces the result:

```
id          orderNO     lineItemNO  orderStatus       minStat           maxStat
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------------- ----------------- -----------------
4           101         1           Pending           Pending           Pending
5           101         2           Pending           Pending           Pending
```

Comment: thanks for the answer it has been worked. thanks a lot